# How to enable backpressure in Spark Streaming (using pyspark)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I would like know what would be the correct way of enable `backpressure` in `spark streaming` through `pyspark`. It looks like I have too many messages sent from `Kafka` in a short time and explode to it. Below is my code for `spark streaming`. Can anyone point me to the correct place to enable `back pressure`?

```
sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingDirectKafka")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 5)
ssc.checkpoint("/spark_check/")
kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [kafka_topic],
                                    {"metadata.broker.list": bootstrap_servers_ipaddress})
parsed_msg = kvs.map(lambda (key, value): json.loads(value))
## do something below
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how i set backpressure in my kafka streaming code.
Hope it helps.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("PythonStreamingDirectKafka")\
        .set("spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled", "true") \
        .set("spark.streaming.backpressure.initialRate", "500")

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```